# How to have distinct key value pair from hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I got a hash in following format:

```
{"A"=> 0, "B"=> 0, "C"=> 1, "D"=> 3, "E"=> 0}
```

And I want to have this hash with no duplicate value pairs. 
For instance, desired output is:

```
{ "A"=> 0, "C"=>1, "D"=>3 }
```

Comment: If multiple keys have the same value, which one of those keys do you wish to keep, or does it matter?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No does not matter. For instance in the above example it's okay to get result with "A" => 0 or "B" => 0. Just I need value 0 to appear only once in the result !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. convert to *Array*, use `uniq` and convert back to *Hash*:

   ```
   Hash[some_hash.to_a.uniq(&:last)]
   ```
2. invert keys and values and invert back:

   ```
   some_hash.invert.invert
   ```
3. use `set` :

   ```
   require 'set'
   set = Set.new
   some_hash.select{ |_,v| !set.include?(v).tap{ set << v } }
   ```

**Pay attention #1/#3 takes first elements while #2 takes the last ones**

```
h = {a: 0, b: 1, c: 0, d: 2, e: 1}
Hash[h.to_a.uniq(&:last)] # {a: 0, b: 1, d: 2}
h.invert.invert           # {c: 0, d: 2, e: 1}
```

**Benchmark** ('a'..'zzz' hash)

```
        user     system      total        real
 #1   0.040000   0.010000   0.050000 (  0.040964)
 #2   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.002194)
 #3   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.010814)
```

Comment: Note: @TheShalit  The .invert option does not work as we have duplicate values.

Comment: @Ajay, that's precisely why TheShalit used `invert`: `{"A"=> 0, "B"=> 0, "C"=> 1, "D"=> 3, "E"=> 0}.invert #=> {0=>"E", 1=>"C", 3=>"D"}`, then `{0=>"E", 1=>"C", 3=>"D"}.invert #=> {"E"=>0, "C"=>1, "D"=>3}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
h = {"A"=> 0, "B"=> 0, "C"=> 1, "D"=> 3, "E"=> 0}
arr = []
h.each {|k,v| arr.include?(v) ? h.delete(k) : arr << v }
#=> {"A"=>0, "C"=>1, "D"=>3}
```